# Need to rank duplicate text values in a column Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have some 300 names in a column, I want to rank them and want to include duplicate values eg: if Smith is #3 and #4 on list, they will be put there.

my Current code, which is not working:

```
Sub karp()
Dim Prescribers As Worksheets
Dim n, r, LR As Long
Dim name1, name2 As String

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row

    For n = 4 To LR         'to loop through the range for a match
        For a = 1 To 273    'number of possible name ranks
            Sheets("Names").Cells(n, 3) = a                       'places rank score
                name1 = Sheets("Names").Cells(n, 3).Value         'checks name
                name2 = Sheets("Names").Cells(n + 1, 3).Value     'checks next name
            If name1 <> name2 Then
        Next a
        Next n
             End If
    Next n

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on a repair?

Comment: You are attempting to do your `Next` statements within an `If...Then` statement. You have to have the `End If` _before_ the `Next` - you can't cross scope. You also have 3 `Next` and only 2 `For`. You're going to have to rework that from the top down. I'm not even sure what the point of having the `If` statement in this block of code is.

Comment: Note that this would have been evident if you properly indented your code.

Comment: @Bob22: Your question is not very clear as it stands, maybe you could show us a table in your question to help us understand better what you want to do - also, as [Freeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2344413/freeman) says, your code as it is makes no sense...

Comment: @Bob22: What do you want your code to do if `If name1 <> name2 `? And what do you want the code to do if `If name1 = name2 `?

Comment: @Bob22: I think you could rank these names with a simple formula, no need for VBA. But first, please clarify your question and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I need to show the same rank number for duplicate names in a list, eg, 1-Smith, 2-Fox, 2-Fox, 3-Brown, 4-Jones, 4-Jones, 5-Henry

Comment: BTW, are you aware that you need to declare each variable type? In the above, n, r, and name1 will be variants.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the declaring issue; that is not my problem for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I correctly understood then you can use this:

```
Sub karp()
    Dim i&, Cl As Range, rn&
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
    rn = 1
    For Each Cl In Range("C4:C" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(Trim(Cl.Value) & Trim(Cl.Offset(, 1).Value)) Then
            Dic.Add Trim(Cl.Value) & Trim(Cl.Offset(, 1).Value), rn
            rn = rn + 1
        End If
    Next Cl
    For Each Cl In Range("C4:C" & i)
        Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Dic(Trim(Cl.Value) & Trim(Cl.Offset(, 1).Value))
    Next Cl
End Sub
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Pretty much genius Vasily! I'm not sure why it works but it does. I have to figure out how to move ranking from 2 columns over to one to the left but I'm assuming that is the offset. Thank you, thank you!